# How to add a custom field to the resulting Exact online XML feed using a query with Invantive Data Access Point?

Tags: exact-online, invantive-sql

For a customer we are building a custom made XML feed, but they added a custom field (Soort ProductDescription) in their Exact Online administration. How to get that extra field into the XML feed using Data Access Point?

Comment: Where exactly did the user set that field?

Comment: If you mean on `Items`, you could find the name of the field in [this list](https://start.exactonline.nl/docs/HlpRestAPIResourcesDetails.aspx?name=LogisticsItems).

Comment: Yes, it's on Items. They called the extra field 'Soort ProductDescription'.

Comment: That list is for the API, I use the Data Access Point to generate an XML feed. Can I just add fields in the query I use?

Comment: Yes. You can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the Exact Online custom field was configured, the field should be visible in one of the `Free*Field_**` fields mentioned in this [list of fields on `Items`](https://start.exactonline.nl/docs/HlpRestAPIResourcesDetails.aspx?name=LogisticsItems).

You could try to select all fields (`select * from logistics.Items`) and see which field exactly contains the data you expected. I guess it is in `FreeTextField_01`, but it could be in another field.

Comment: I see that I get more information in the XML feed when I use select * from logistics.ItemsRead

Comment: The free field is probably an item classification. The XML and REST variants are not exchangeable; some fields are available in XML, some are in REST. You might want to check out both: select * from exactonlinexml..items and select * from exactonlinerest..items.

Comment: Whatever I try, I'm not getting FreeTextField_01 in the XML feed. The only 'Free*' fields I'm getting in the XML are 'FreeBoolField_0*'.

Comment: I see, try `ItemsRead`. I see they have added some fields to `Items`.

Comment: I've tried `ItemsRead` and that table has more fields indeed. The `FreeTextField_01` field is specified in the `<Fields>` part of the XML, but isn't included in the rows anywhere.

Comment: Can you try and see if there is a value in it in the XML export from within Exact Online itself?

Comment: The information the client writes in the custom field isn't returned anywhere in the XML. The only fields I get in the output are `FreeBoolField_01 FreeBoolField_02 FreeBoolField_03 FreeBoolField_04 FreeBoolField_05` and `Class_01 Class_02`, which is weird because the other `Free*` fields are specified in the `<fields></fields>`. All the other information outputted is correct.